# denied access when I try to open/access a file with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

It's my first time writing a question, sorry if I did something wrong.

I wrote this sample code to show the error and I am running on Windows:

```
import subprocess as sp
inp = sp.run(['find', '/n', '"es"', 'test.txt'], shell=True, capture_output=True, text= True)
print(inp.stdout)
print(inp.returncode)
print(inp.stderr)
```

*The "test.txt" file contains the following:

```
that is a test
jeje
end
```

The output:

```
---------- TEST.TXT

1

Access is denied: \
```

when I run `find /n "je" test.txt` directly in CMD there is no problem. I suppose it might be related with any kind of administration permission... so I run VSCode as admin, but there is no way. I didn't found a similar error on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd do this to troubleshoot: 1) try running your code from command line 2) try just reading the contents of the file, without 'subprocess', from VSCode and command line.

Answer (score 0):

how about if you try using `os.popen`

```py
import os

inp = os.popen('find /n "es" test.txt')
print(inp.read())
```

subprocess does not seem to work in this case so you might like the above workaround. Also if the file you are trying to find contains space in its name then replace `test.txt` with `"some big file name.txt"`